# Find out if column contains two distinct values for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-division

I want to select the rows which satisfy both conditions of the same column. Below is the table schema.

**Security Table**

```
Id  RoleId  CompId  SecurityToken       Accesstype
1   1           10           abc        2
2   1           10           xyz        2
3   12          10           abc        2
4   16          12           abc        2
5   16          12           xyz        2
6   30          13           abc        2
7   1           10           efg        2
8   1           10           lmn        0
```

I want "All rows for each RoleID/CompID combination where accesstype = 2 and there is both a row containing securitytoken "abc" and a row containing SecurityToken "xyz" for that role/compID combination"

**Output should be**

```
Id  RoleId  CompId  SecurityToken       Accesstype
1   1           10           abc        2
2   1           10           xyz        2
4   16          12           abc        2
5   16          12           xyz        2
```

Comment: "the rows which Securitytoken are 'abc' and 'xyz'"...there are no rows which match that criteria. The row cannot contain both values simultaneously. Did you mean "rows where Securitytoken is 'abc' **or** 'xyz'". You may think I'm being pedantic but you should try to define your requirement 100% clearly, then there is no potential for confusion. Small details are important.

Comment: Or, given your expected output, maybe you actually want "All rows for each RoleID/CompID combination where accesstype = 2 and there is both a row containing securitytoken "abc" and a row containing SecurityToken "xyz" for that role/compID combination". That's quite different to what you actually wrote, but I think it's what you probably mean in reality.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion i have updated my requirement

Comment: Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Nevertheless this is also a faq.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the following query will produce the desired output:

```
SELECT *
FROM testdata
WHERE Accesstype = 2
AND SecurityToken IN ('abc', 'xyz')
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM testdata AS tmp
    WHERE RoleId = testdata.RoleId 
    AND CompId = testdata.CompId
    AND Accesstype = testdata.AccessType
    AND SecurityToken IN ('abc', 'xyz')
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SecurityToken) = 2
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1b285/1)

In order to eliminate sets that contain extra security tokens (such as `efg` and `lmn`) change the WHERE and HAVING clause to:

```
    WHERE RoleId = testdata.RoleId 
    AND CompId = testdata.CompId
    AND Accesstype = testdata.AccessType
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SecurityToken) = 2
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT SecurityToken) = COUNT(CASE WHEN SecurityToken IN ('abc', 'xyz') THEN 1 END)
```

Comment: @vishal see revised answer. I don't see anything wrong with my original or revised answer (except it will now skip unnecessary rows).

Comment: @Chanukya Please don't hijack answer comments pointing to your own answer. It's not relevant to the conversation. The OP will have received notification that you answered, that should be enough.

Comment: @ Salman A  : I think we are close but not exact output, I have modified the table data. please check with that data.

Comment: @vishal the above query produces same result. Do you want to skip `1, 10` because it contains extra security token (`efg`)?

Comment: Yes It worked .         SELECT *
FROM testdata
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM testdata tmp
  WHERE RoleId = testdata.RoleId 
  AND CompId = testdata.CompId
  AND SecurityToken IN ('abc', 'xyz')
  AND Accesstype = 2
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SecurityToken) = 2
)  AND SecurityToken IN ('abc', 'xyz')
  AND Accesstype = 2                                      thank you very Much

Comment: I understand the answer -- which though close is not what the OP is asking for (it works, but only under certain assumptions).  I don't understand the upvotes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I believe OP wants simple relational division.

Comment: @SalmanA . . . This assumes no duplicates for the `securityToken` for the a given combination of keys.  That is supported by the data, but it is a key assumption about the data, one that the OP does not state.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes it does assume that by looking at the data. One could simply change `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT SecurityToken)` (my original answer had this, but OP mentioned that it was not working, I removed it in my edit later).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([Id] int, [RoleId] int, [CompId] int, [SecurityToken] varchar(3), [Accesstype] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([Id], [RoleId], [CompId], [SecurityToken], [Accesstype])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 10, 'abc', 2),
    (2, 1, 10, 'xyz', 2),
    (3, 12, 10, 'abc', 2),
    (4, 16, 12, 'abc', 2),
    (5, 16, 12, 'xyz', 2),
    (6, 30, 13, 'abc', 2)
;
WITH cte AS (
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ROLEID],[COMPID] ORDER BY ID) AS RN FROM #TABLE1
),
COUNTED AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [ROLEID],[COMPID]) AS CNT
  FROM cte
)
SELECT
[ID], [ROLEID], [COMPID], [SECURITYTOKEN], [ACCESSTYPE]
FROM COUNTED
WHERE CNT >= 2
```

output

```
ID  ROLEID  COMPID  SECURITYTOKEN   ACCESSTYPE
1   1        10            abc          2
2   1        10            xyz          2
4   16       12            abc          2
5   16       12            xyz          2
```

or

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [ROLEID],[COMPID]) AS CNT
  FROM #TABLE1)
  SELECT [ID], [ROLEID], [COMPID], [SECURITYTOKEN], [ACCESSTYPE] FROM CTE WHERE CNT>=2
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.Accesstype = 2 and
      t.securityToken in ('abc', 'xyz') and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.RoleId = t.RoleId and
                    t2.CompId = t.CompId and
                    t2.Accesstype = t.AccessType and
                    t2.SecurityToken in ('abc', 'xyz') and
                    t2.SecrityToken <> t.SecurityToken
             );
```

Perhaps a simpler method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(securitytoken) over (partition by roleid, compid) as min_st,
             min(securitytoken) over (partition by roleid, compid) as max_st
      from t
      where t.Accesstype = 2 and
            t.SecurityToken in ('abc', 'xyz')
     ) t
where minsecuritytoken = 'abc' and
      maxsecuritytoken = 'xyz;
```

Comment: (not verified but apparently) if you try to apply this logic to more than two values (e.g. you want to check if all of abc, xyz, xxx are present) it fails.

Comment: @SalmanA . . . I would handle more than two values a bit differently.  This question is about two values.